# Throttling or backing-off web requests with C#

Tags: c#, rest, parallel-processing

I'm writing a program that has to make a few thousand REST API calls as quickly as possible.  If I make them all serially (i.e. one after the other) then there is no bottle-neck, but the host of the REST API could handle them in parallel.... up to a point.

I have parallelised the code that issues the requests, but I've noticed there is a "sweet spot" in terms of how many requests the REST API can handle at once.

My current approach is to parallelise across, say, 4 threads and time how long each request takes to complete.  I time all requests with a stopwatch and calculate the average.  If the average time starts to increase then I increase an artificial delay before making the next request; if the average starts to decrease then I decrease the delay.  However, I notice over time the average time still creeps up which means I've over-stepped the sweet spot.

What I'm looking for is some guidance or advice on how to find and track this sweet spot.  Examples in C# would be gratefully received, but I'd also be interested in ideas in principle.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use a reverse proxy to do load balancing?

Comment: Fairly good question... not something I'd thought of to be honest.  You mean flood the API with requests and let load balancer handle it?

Comment: Yes, as long as you have additional "machines" this would probably be the easier route if you're just trying to achieve a certain throughput

Comment: I'd prefer to do it on one machine to be honest.  Like I said, this is about fine-tuning to find an absolute sweet spot more than anything.  I think a load balancer will be a blunt instrument for achieving that goal.